# What is a layman's term for internet-enabled or web-enabled?

Tags: terminology, wording

I need a better term for internet-enabled or web-enabled that a non-technical person would understand includes their smartphone, tablet, laptop, desktop, smartTV, etc.

Comment: I would think that either of _internet-enabled_ or _web-enabled_ is fine if what you want to say is what they mean.

Comment: "Online"...?  "Online devices"/"The thneed is online"...

Comment: Perhaps "with internet access"?

Comment: VTC: This question seems likely to solicit a large number of two-to-three word responses.

Comment: @3nafish Is this neccesarily a bad thing? A rated list of easy-to-understand phrasings of the term internet-enabled is a useful artifact left for the internet and future visitors. The answer below, though good, is not more useful than a short version of the same answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

For one, I think @Dan D. is correct in saying that those terms by themselves should be pretty clear.

If you're looking for something that a very un-tech-savvy (surely that's a word) crowd could understand, I'd say swapping the word "enabled" with "connected" could work, even though it wouldn't be ideal.

Perhaps "always online"?

That'd be the only thing I can think of, short of changing it into a sentence like "devices that are connected to the internet" or @Kristoffer Nolgren's "with internet access".